# How can I find the maximum or minimum of a multi-dimensional matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, max, min

I have a 4D array of measurements in MATLAB. Each dimension represents a different parameter for the measurement. I want to find the maximum and minimum value and the index (i.e. which parameter) of each.

What's the best way to do it? I figure I can take the max of the max of the max in each dimension, but that seems like a kludge.

Comment: Though the explicit question is answered in the flagged dupe, all of the answers here are answering the question in the title. These are two very distinct scenarios and I do not agree with the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Quick example:

```
%# random 4 d array with different size in each dim
A = rand([3,3,3,5]);

%# finds the max of A and its position, when A is viewed as a 1D array
[max_val, position] = max(A(:)); 

%#transform the index in the 1D view to 4 indices, given the size of A
[i,j,k,l] = ind2sub(size(A),position);
```

Finding the minimum is left as an exercise :).

Following a comment:
If you do not know the number of dimensions of your array A and cannot therefore write the "`[i,j,k,l] =`" part, use this trick:

```
indices = cell(1,length(size(A)));

[indices{:}] = ind2sub(size(A),position);
```

Comment: This is the Matlab way. If you want to find the absolute maximum, use `max(abs(A(:))` and multiply with `sign(A(position))` in case you're interested in the sign.

Comment: Nice solution which does it in the Matlab way without any loops.

Comment: Can you get a max position indices as a vector if you don't know A's dimensions? In a function, for example.

Comment: @Adrien: Please have a look at the FAQ to see how to format your posts.

Comment: a convenient function to solve that last comment is IND2SUBV written by *Tom Minka* as part of his Lightspeed Toolbox: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/ , you can find the function here: http://pmtk3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/util/ind2subv.m

Answer (score 0):

for two dimensional array, say I
you can just use the min /max function twice.
n times for n dimensional array.
eg:  `a=[2 3 4; 5 6 7; -2 7 87; 911 7 34];`

```
for minimum:  min(min(a,[],1))
             ->  the answer will be -2.
```

you can put the dimension parameter in min/max to 2 as well. as this is calling the function twice, second time on the minimum/maximum element vector of the dimension u choose.

similarly, you can do `(max(max(a,[],1))` to find out the maximum.