# How do I get the index of the smallest element in an array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How do I get the index of the smallest element in an array in matlab?

Comment: the same answer from this question applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673804/matlab-matrix-question

Comment: Related: [How can I find the maximum or minimum of a multi-dimensional matrix in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635120/how-can-i-find-the-maximum-or-minimum-of-a-multi-dimensional-matrix-in-matlab)

Comment: dup: [matlab - argmax and argmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/matlab-argmax-and-argmin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[C,I] = min(...)` finds the indices of the minimum values of `A`, and returns them in output vector `I`. If there are several identical minimum values, the index of the first one found is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`min()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) function with 2 output arguments.  The first returned value will be the value, the second will be the index of that value.