# Index of max and min value in an array

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I find the index of the maximum element in an array without looping?

For example, if I have:

```
a = [1 2 999 3];
```

I want to define a function `indexMax` so that `indexMax(a)` would return `3`.

Likewise for defining `indexMin`.

Comment: There is a problem with this question. @EvgeniSergeev does want to find the index of the max or min value in an array. He is using the name "argmax" for it (and the made up function "argmax(a)"). But argmax is something different (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max). Therefor this question is really confusing if you are really looking for an argmax function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As pointed by [Evgeni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556734/1714410) [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) can return the `argmax` and `argmin` as second arguments.
It is worth while noting that you can use these functions *along specific dimensions*:

```
 A = rand(4); % 4x4 matrix
 [ row_max row_argmax ] = max( A, [], 2 ); % max for each row - 2nd dimension
 [ col_min col_argmin ] = min( A, [], 1 ); % min for each column - 1st dimension
```

Note the empty `[]` second argument - it is crucial `max( A, [], 2 )` is **not at all** equivalent to `max( A, 2 )` (I'll leave it to you as a small exercise to see what `max( A, 2 )` does).

The argmax/argmin returned from these "along dimension" calls are row/col indices.

Comment: Solution to the exercise: `max(X, Y)` is an element-wise max (just like `.*` is an element-wise multiply) ... with the usual scalar behaviour, viz. sizes of `X` and `Y` must be the same or one of them can be a scalar.

Comment: Mmmm ... it's good getting all those points. I just haven't decided how am I going to spend it yet.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev - hide them under your bed!

Comment: That doesn't leave much I could say in reply.

Answer (score 24):

The built-in `max` function has this functionality when two output arguments are specified:

```
a = [1 2 999 3];
[the_max, index_of_max] = max(a)

the_max =

   999


index_of_max =

     3
```

Likewise for `min`.

Answer (score 7):

Just as an alternative solution, you might try this:

```
a = rand(1,1000);
min_idx = find(a == min(a));
```

Obviously, the same procedure is applicable in the case of `max`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is useful in cases where there may be several equal-maximum elements and one wishes to get all of their indices.