# Finding maximum index of a row of array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I want to get the index of a specific row in a 2-D array. I have a 15*15 array (Q), and I want to get index of the maximum number of 2nd row.
I wrote this code, but an error occurred:

```
y=Q(2,:);
x=max(y)
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Comment: You shouldn't get this error message from the code you provided. This is not where you are getting the error. Plus, you are getting the **value** and not the **index**.

Comment: OK, But I don't know how to get index of it

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab - argmax and argmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/matlab-argmax-and-argmin)

Comment: please check that you did not overwrite `max`: type `which max` and see if it returns a "built-in function" or a matrix/variable

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the maximum *value* of the second row, but you want the *index* of the maximum value. Here's how to get the index:

```
[~, index] = max(y)
```

Comment: the maximum numbers are multiple , but I want to get index of one of them

Comment: @irisadaf I think the error is not in the code shown. If `y` is a vector, the above code works just fine.

Comment: How to recognize this row is vector or not? this row (y) gets from Q array of double numbers

Comment: @irisadaf A vector is a 1xN, or Nx1 array. Are you sure that `y` is a vector? I think you have problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I think my MATLAB has some errors , because I wrote b=[1,2,3] and write max(b) , this error shown :??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.!!!!!!!!!