# Getting Matlab to return values in a table based on other values in the same table

Tags: matlab, indexing, max

I'm looking for the date/time in which the maximum temperature occurs in a table with 2 columns: Date/Time and Temperature.
so its:

```
Date/Time    Temperature
3/4/15 1000  27
3/4/15 1100  28    
3/4/15 1200  29  
...          ...
```

So in other words how can I get the program to spit out the date/time in which the maximum temperature occurs for me?

Comment: Use the second output of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to get the index of the largest element.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/matlab-argmax-and-argmin