# Finding indexes of maximum values of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

How do I find the index of the 2 maximum values of a 1D array in MATLAB? Mine is an array with a list of different scores, and I want to print the 2 highest scores.

Comment: Use `sort` and pick the last two values

Comment: hey, 
thank you, 

but as i did sorting, than the indexes are changing, 
could you be more specific?

Comment: What's the desired output? The values, the indices, or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of max and min value in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/index-of-max-and-min-value-in-an-array)

Comment: @Spen I disagree with that proposed duplicate, as the solutions there only give *one* index, which is indeed quite easy with the second output of `min` and `max`. Getting the *second* maximum value requires either an extension of the duplicate's answers (see beaker's answer for that) or a different approach altogether (see Luis' `sort` method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), as @LuisMendo suggested:

```
[B,I] = sort(array,'descend');
```

This gives you the sorted version of your `array` in the variable `B` and the indexes of the original position in `I` sorted from highest to lowest. Thus, `B(1:2)` gives you the highest two values and `I(1:2)` gives you their indices in your `array`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for an `O(k*n)` solution, where `k` is the number of maximum values you're looking for, rather than `O(n log n)`:

```
x = [3 2 5 4 7 3 2 6 4];
y = x; %// make a copy of x because we're going to modify it
[~, m(1)] = max(y);
y(m(1)) = -Inf;
[~, m(2)] = max(y);

m =

   5   8
```

This is only practical if `k` is less than `log n`. In fact, if `k>=3` I would put it in a loops, which may offend the sensibilities of some. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get the indices of the two largest elements: use the second output of [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to get the sorted indices, and then pick the last two:

```
x = [3 2 5 4 7 3 2 6 4];
[~, ind] = sort(x);
result = ind(end-1:end);
```

In this case,

```
result =
     8     5
```