# How to set in Matlab the min value of each row (or column) in array?

Tags: matlab, min

I have an array in matlab, e.g.

```
a=rand([3,3])
a =

0.8308    0.9172    0.7537
0.5853    0.2858    0.3804
0.5497    0.7572    0.5678
```

And now, I would like to set the min value of each row to 0. The result should be:

```
a =

0.8308    0.9172    0
0.5853    0         0.3804
0         0.7572    0.5678
```

I have no idea how to use `[Y,I]=min(a,[],2)` function for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you can get the column index of the minimal value of each row using

```
[~, col] = min(a, [], 2);
```

Now you can use `sub2ind` to set the entries to zero:

```
a( sub2ind(size(a), 1:size(a,1), col.') ) = 0;
```

You can play with it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/YQDbYO).

Comment: Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket. I clear the last bracket, but still do not work..

Comment: Error using sub2ind
The subscript vectors must all be of the same size. Still not working.

Comment: @IvoVertat fixed.

Comment: Excellent. Great job. Thanks.

Comment: @IvoVertat if this solution worked for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "v" icon beside it. thanks!

Comment: more on `argmin` in matlab, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556850/1714410)

Answer (score 2):

If you are concern about multiple minima in the same row:

```
row_min = min(a, [], 2);
a( bsxfun(@eq, row_min, a) ) = 0;
```

No loops are needed (as opposed to [Matt T's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496057/1714410) answer).

Comment: It works well and easy to extend for multidimensional array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One inefficient method would be to loop through each row and use the find command to find all minima in a particular row.

```
n = 10;
A = rand(n,n);    
for ii = 1:n
ind = find(A(ii,:) == min(A(ii,:)));
A(ii,ind) = 0;
end
```

If there are multiple minima, this will set all of these to zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no need for loop. better use logical indexing instead of `find`.