# matlab identify position of min and max

Tags: matlab, time-series, max, min

I have a time series and have calculated the min, max and mean values. However, I want to know at which year the min and max observations occurred. How is it possible to identify the ith position of the min and max values in the dataset?

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html), both output an index as the second output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of max and min value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/index-of-max-and-min-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You find it using `find` command.

for example:

```
M = [1992, 3 ,5; 1997, 8 ,2; 2000, 2, 15]
[~,min_i] = min(M(:,2)) %return the row index of min vaule in the 2nd column.
year_of_min = M(min_i,1)
```