# MATLAB equivalent to Python argmax with array of user defined objects

Tags: matlab, class, object, argmax

I have an array as shown here. Here `Bandit` is a class that I created.

```
bandits = [Bandit(m1),Bandit(m2),Bandit(m3)];
```

Now, I want to do the following. Following is Python code which immediately gives me the maxarg of the value of the mean of each of these objects.

```py
j = np.argmax([b.mean for b in bandits])
```

How can I do the same in MATLAB? To give more clarity, every bandit object has an attribute `mean_value`. I.e. if `b1` is a bandit object, then I can get that value using dot operator (`b1.mean_value`). I want to find which among `b1`, `b2`, `b3` has maximum `mean_val` and need to get the index for it. (See the python code above. If `b2` has the highest `mean_val`, then finally, `j` will contain index 2.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of max and min value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/index-of-max-and-min-value-in-an-array)

Comment: Also on matlabcentral: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76467-how-do-i-find-argmax

Comment: Not at all. My question is more specific. The array contains objects of a user-defined class. I want to select the index of an object whose mean (ie egLobject1.mean) is maximum. In Python, it is a one-liner. Want to knowhow this can be done in MATLAB

Comment: @DavidParks: This is not a duplicate of that question. The answer there only works for numeric arrays, not for arrays of a custom type.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) applies a function to each element of an array. It results in a new array with the results of the operation. To this result you can then apply `max` as usual:

```
[~,arg] = max(arrayfun(@mean,bandits));
```

Note that this might not work if you have overloaded the `subsref` or `size` methods for the `Bandit` class.

---

**Edit:**

So now I understand that `mean` was not a function but an attribute. The operation `x.mean` can be expressed as the function call `subsref(x,substruct('.','mean'))`. Thus, it is possible to change the solution above to call this function on each array element:

```
op = @(x)subsref(x,substruct('.','mean'))
[~,arg] = max(arrayfun(op,bandits));
```

That is, instead of calling the function `mean`, we call the function `subsref` to index the attribute `mean`.

If `bandits` is a simple struct array, then the following will work also:

```
[~,arg] = max([bandits.mean]);
```

Here, `bandits.mean` will extract the `mean` value for each element of the struct array, yielding a comma-separated list. This list is captured with the square brackets to form a vector. This vector is again input into the `max` function as usual.

I'm not sure if this latter solution works also for custom classes. I don't have your `Bandit` class to test. Please let me know if this latter solution works, so I can update the post with correct information.

Comment: To give more clarity, every bandit object has an attribute 'mean_value'. ie If b1 is a bandit object, then I can get that value using dot operator (b1.mean_value). I want to find which among b1,b2,b3 has maximum mean_val and need to get the index for it (see the python code above. It loops through bandits array. Check which among b1,b2,b3 has mean_val as maximum. If b2 has the highest mean_val, then finally, j will contain index 2)

Comment: @user3137598: I have edited the answer, I hope the nicer solution works for custom classes, but I don't know. Otherwise, the ugly solution can be used. :)