# MATLAB: Print the indexes alongside an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new to using MATLAB and I have an array of size [131 x 4]. I am looking to locate the row which contains the highest and lowest value in column 2. (my first column is used to label, the next three are used as coordinates)

I want to be able to extract the rows which contain the highest and lowest value in column 2, for example if I knew its index was 5, I would use:

```
LARGESTX = MYARRAY(5,:)
```

The MATLAB website gives instructions on how to select particular elements of an array by using indexing, but with my array being so large I can't eyeball the index of the largest/smallest values.

Is there a method which will print the indexes of each row alongside my array? Or to create a new array with the indexes appended on to each row?

Comment: The question is phrased differently, because you've gone down the path of solving the problem your way (by displaying), but the root of the problem is a duplicate of [Index of max and min value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556733/index-of-max-and-min-value-in-an-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 2nd outputs of `min` and `max` to simply get the indices, there is no need to "eyeball" the correct row from displaying the whole matrix!

```
[~,minIdx] = min( myarray(:,2) ); % minIdx is the row in column 2 with the min value
[~,maxIdx] = max( myarray(:,2) ); % maxIdx is the row in column 2 with the max value
```

Then you can index as you suggested

```
smallestRow = myarray( minIdx, : );
largestRow = myarray( maxIdx, : );
```

---

Note I've used a tilde (`~`) in place of a variable for the first outputs of `min` and `max` because I'm not interested in those outputs. The tilde causes the first outputs to be discarded.

---

Aside from that, the easiest way to do what you've actually asked (display array with row numbers) is to look at the array in the workspace. This will give you a table with row and column numbers.

[image: table]